# Clustering bitcoin addresses with k-means - how would one prepare input

Tags: clustering, k-means, preprocessing

I am looking to perform clustering on bitcoin addresses within the blockchain. I have generated a graph structure of the blockchain with a source address, destination address, value of transaction, in-degree, out-degree.

I think misunderstanding lies in the fact that this is directed graph.

How could this information be represented as input to the k-means clustering algorithm? Should nodes and their corresponding features be the input to k-means alone and should the directed (source/destination) element be removed from the input data?

Example data:

```
source address | destination address | transaction value | timestamp | in-degree | out-degree | pagerank | tags
```

`source and destination` addresses are just a public key of a sender and receiver of the bitcoin.

`transaction value` would be the number of bitcoins you would want to send.

`in-degree` would show the number of links (transactions in this case) pointing in to a given node

`out-degree` would show the number of links (transactions in this case) pointing out of a given node

`pagerank` is a number showing the importance of a node by the number of other important nodes linking to it.

`tags` will be string based descriptions of an addresses known activity. For example, some gambling companies publish their addresses so we can associate transactions involving this address as a gambling transaction.

Comment: The input of *any* clustering algorithm is always the initial set of data together with an additional label that, for each data, specifies the cluster they belong to. What in particular do you want to represent?

Comment: I want to determine clusters of 'users/addresses' with similar transactional behaviour. I forgot to mention that one of the features will be a categorised tag of the transaction. ie. transactions to gambling sites will be tagged, donations to charities etc.

Comment: What is the particular problem that prevents you from doing so? Define a distance between points (to calculate similarities according to your data) and define a clustering method of your choice based on that distance.

Comment: I suppose the problem is that I am struggling to understand the way in which this type of data would be represented in a dimensional space. I understand [this](http://johnloeber.com/docs/kmeans.html) example in a 2d space but can't quite see how the transactional (source/destination) representation would work. Perhaps i am missing something very obvious and should consider an address as undirected/without edges and with only attributes about the node itself.

Comment: I think you're making confusion among many different things. Is the clustering that you want to achieve or what else? If so, what are the edges and nodes you're talking about? Each point is represented, in your data set, by a set of coordinates (which we have no idea about because you didn't give any data source): cluster the points according to the sub-set of coordinates you want to consider and you should be done already.

Comment: your right, i have confused myself. i want clustering on bitcoin user/addresses. a node is a user/address, an edge is the transaction from one user/address to another. the transaction will contain features such as category. the user/address will also contain features. ill update my question to show sample data.

Comment: Most people are not very intricate with bitcoin transactions, could you show a few lines and explain every column in one or a few lines?

Comment: So the in and out-degree are part of a transaction? So they refer to earlier transactions?

Comment: Sorry i didn't make that part clear, the degrees and page rank hold information about the address within the network as a whole, not specific to that transaction. So they take into account previous transactions as well.

Comment: Have you solved the problem yet? I have the same problem with you.It's been bothering me for a long time.Thanks！